# How to delete last character in a string with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

in this example below I want to remove the "B" using VBA. Thus, I download these values which spam from B5:F50 and all in the end have "B". My question is twofold. A) Is there a way to delete the "B" using VBA and replace these values in the same cells? B) Or have to be in new cells?

`77.65B 86.73B  92.97B  84.7B   89.4B`

Comment: A) Yes. B) No you can use the same cells

Comment: To add to what @CLR said, declare B5:F50 a range, Loop through each cell in the range and, in each iteration, set the cell value = Left([Cell value],Len(trim([Cell Value]))-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (shortest) way I can see to do this is with a Search/Replace, *but this would be on the assumption that all cells end in B and a B doesn't legitimately occur elsewhere in the cells.*

```
Sheets("YourSheetNameHere").Range("B5:F50").Replace What:="B", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Alternatively, you could loop through each cell and `RIGHT`/`LEN` etc. but why bother?

Answer (score 1):

The code would be like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range, vDB
    Dim s As String, i As Integer, j As Integer

    Set rngDB = Range("b5:f50")
    vDB = rngDB
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    For i = 1 To r
        For j = 1 To c
            s = vDB(i, j)
            s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
            vDB(i, j) = s
        Next j
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB

End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rngDB As Range        
    Set rngDB = Range("b5:f50")
    rngDB.Replace "B", "", lookat:=xlPart

End Sub
```